# How useful is the 24-70 lens?

Tags: lens, lens-recommendation

I am an amateur photographer. For the past few months I have been shooting with my 50 mm lens. Recently I am getting booked for more shoots, like family photos and maternity. It was suggested that I rent a 24-70 lens. Can someone please give me insight on the lens for those types of shoots and if it it worth buying? Will I use it a lot? I also want to say that in my future I want to be doing weddings.

I would like to say it would be for full frame.

Comment: You need to be more specific. A good zoom in that range could be very useful even professionally, a cheap one could be handy for just learning, but you'd soon find its weaknesses. You should also specify full frame or cropped sensor, as that changes the effective focal length.

Answer (score 6):

Most professional setups start with a 24-70/2.8 and 70-200/2.8 two-lens combo **on full frame** and work outwards from there. These are the two general-purpose bread'and'butter lenses for a lot of pros simply because they're versatile being both fast (f/2.8) and zooms in the most common focal length ranges. Whether or not they'll be ideal for you, however, is not something we can answer. Lens choices are individual and a lot of factors such as what/how you plan to shoot and your personal budget are also huge determining factors that only you really know.  People can tell you what works for *them* very easily. Telling you what will work for you is less easily arrived at.

It's super-easy to tank a photography business with gear greed.  A 24-70/70-200 f/2.8 combo is expensive (upwards of $2500) as is a full-frame body. If you have to make your business go into the red to purchase these lenses, it's probably a very bad idea. Because we all know a lens alone isn't enough to guarantee an image.  In addition, the 24-70 is designed for full frame. On a crop body, a 17-50ish/2.8 lens is FoV equivalent to what a 24-70/2.8 does on full frame.

But maybe you only need an 85/1.8.  Or specialized software. [Or a flash](http://neilvn.com/tangents/flash-photography-techniques/bouncing-flash/). Or [off-camera flash](http://www.strobist.com) gear and knowledge. Before buying something, you should know whether or not you need it, and it doesn't sound like you do. What is your 50mm **not** doing that you need to do?  Start there.

Renting can be a good way to use only a small amount of money to try a lens before sinking money into purchasing it.  Until you gain a wide degree of experience with lenses, it's tough to know what you want, and renting is one way to experience a lens with enough time to learn its ins and outs.